# Ubuntu 19.10 Network Connection Dropping Repeatedly - I think due to WiFi Power Save, which won't stay turned off

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, power-management

I'm a somewhat novice user and have not found a solution to this after much searching, any help is very appreciated.

Summary: My wifi connection keeps dropping and reconnecting about every two minutes. The drop is brief enough that it's only disruptive if I'm streaming video/videochatting or playing an online game. This started a few days ago when my laptop power got low. Given that circumstance, I *think* this is an issue with the WiFi power save setting (WiFi gets automatically turned off to save power). However, ever since then my WiFi connection is cutting out even when my laptop is plugged in and at full power. Also the WiFi power save setting refuses to stay turned off. This is especially annoying because my laptop does not have an ethernet port so a wireless connection is my only option. I'm gonna list some relevant specs and such and then detail what I've tried so far to fix it.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on an HP Envy x360 laptop. I'm using the internal network card which is: product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.

What I've tried:

1. I opened the Power Settings GUI and toggled off "WiFi can be turned off to save power." However this puts my laptop into Airplane Mode, and when I reconnect to WiFi, this setting toggles itself back on.
2. I ran Software Updater to check for driver updates. There were none.
3. I manually edited the Wifi power save config file at /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and set wifi.powersave = 2. This seemingly did nothing.
4. I ran sudo iwconfig wlan1 power off - this also seemingly did nothing.

And of course I've restarted the computer multiple times.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? I can't think what else would be the issue other than the wifi power save setting. I'm including a screenshot of the output of ifconfig (sorry for the hasty editing - I redacted all the IP addresses). I have several VMs (virtualbox and VMWare) that are not running - idk why their networks are showing up in ifconfig output when they're not running? But this has been the case for months with no issues. (This is my first post so I'm not allowed to embed images yet).

Any ideas?

[ifconfig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA4aG.png)

Comment: Try `sudo iwconfig wlo1 power off` as your wifi is wlo1 interface not wlan1

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's what I actually ran (made a mistake in my post). I ran the command again just to be sure and I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Check `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net` is the ID in the first set of brackets [10ec:b822] if so what does `modprobe -c | grep -i b822` show

Comment: Yes to the first question, modprobe output is: alias pci:v000010ECd0000B822sv*sd*bc*sc*i* rtwpci